Issues with ImportTsv - Job Fails with Exit Code 1
I am currently facing an issue while using the ImportTsv command to load data into an HBase table. I am running the command and the job is failing with a non-zero exit code 1.
Hadoop version : 3.4.0
Hbase version : 2.4.18
Data Loading Command :
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf:name,cf:age,cf:gender" -Dimporttsv.separator="\t" my_1 /hbase/test2.txt

ERROR LOG:**
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/super/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/super/hbase/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.33.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]
2024-09-02 09:48:21,871 WARN [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2024-09-02 09:48:22,149 INFO [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x68267da0] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.8.4-9316c2a7a97e1666d8f4593f34dd6fc36ecc436c, built on 2024-02-12 22:16 UTC
2024-09-02 09:48:22,149 INFO [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x68267da0] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=dc1-apache-hbase.____________
...
2024-09-02 09:48:32,995 INFO [main] mapreduce.Job: 8]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Resource Manager Logs:
[2024-09-02 09:48:32.499]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


You'll have a clearer error message in the MapReduce job logs.
